# Strange query by oracle_fdw

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

I am using oracle_fdw 2.2.0devel, PostgreSQL 10.13, Oracle client 18.3.0.0.0

We have a foreign table in Postgres defined as this:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE public.tickers
(
   ticker_id         INTEGER,
   ticker            VARCHAR,
)
SERVER oracle
OPTIONS (table 'TICKERS', schema 'COMMENTARY', readonly 'true');
```

This is connecting to as 12c SE database.   This works fine, however, I've noticed that the query in Oracle is actually looking like this:

```
SELECT  
   /*618157932326e692807010156f98ddac*/  
   r2."TICKER_ID",  
   r2."TICKER"  
FROM "COMMENTARY"."TICKERS" r2  
WHERE (upper(r2."TICKER") = upper(:p1))
```

Why would it automatically be adding the "UPPER" clause?  This slows the Oracle query and does not use an index, unless I create a FBI using "upper".

Was wondering if there was some option I'm supposed to disable.......

Comment: Which PostgreSQL SQL FDW are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the corresponding Postgres query

Comment: Are you asking which version of PSQL?    10.13.    If asking something else, please advise where to find that info, as I may not be sure.   -- Thanks!

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't ship natively with a FDW for Oracle. Where did you get it?

Comment: Ok, it appears to be this:   oracle_fdw 2.2.0devel, PostgreSQL 10.13, Oracle client 18.3.0.0.0

Comment: That cannot be answered without knowing the PostgreSQL query.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that oracle_fdw will generate an Oracle query that uses the `upper` function is if the original PostgreSQL query already had `upper` in it.